# Add characters between string

Tags: c#, .net, string, visual-studio

I have a string like

> A, B, C, D, E

Now I want to add single quotations to this like

> 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'

How can I do this in C#.net?

Thanks.

Comment: how you assign the string?

Comment: Show the code you use to assign the string

Comment: using a text box. user can enter the text with comma. then I want to pass this string to a sql query

Comment: @ChaturangaBandara: Hm... to be used directly in the SQL code? That would make the query wide open for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Imagine the user entering something like `A, B, ';drop table users;--`. If you want to use it like that, you should validate that the input only contains unharmful values.

Comment: yes I'm validating the input.. users are not allowed to type characters like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `string` methods and LINQ combination, you can do it easily:

```
var str = "A, B, C, D, E";
var result = string.Join(", ", 
                         str.Split(',').Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x.Trim())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex...

```
var newstr = Regex.Replace("A, B, C, D, E", @"\w", "'$0'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Replace`:

```
string s = "A, B, C, D, E";
s = "'" + s.Replace(", ", "', '") + "'";
```

Comment: but what if spaces were not given somewhere?

Comment: Cauz he said that user inputs comma seperated values in a textbox

Comment: @Sayka: He also said that it would be used in an SQL query, which makes all answers obsolete because none of them does anything to protect against SQL injection...

Answer (score 0):

```
    string addQuotes(string val)
    {
        string[] ss = val.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string res = "";
        foreach (string s in ss) res += (res == "" ? "" : ", ") + "'" + s + "'";
        return res;
    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = addQuotes(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use `+=` in a loop that you don't know the length of. The performance degrades very quickly. Use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Ouch... The performance time roughly doubles for each iteration using `+=`, so I can imagine that you will make some noticable performance improvements. :)